# Fuse filesystem not calling release

Tags: c, filesystems, fuse

from [the fuse docs](https://libfuse.github.io/doxygen/structfuse__operations.html#abac8718cdfc1ee273a44831a27393419) I thought that on calling close, fuse would call release. However, this does not seem to be the case for my filsystem. I have registered my release function with the following code:

```
static int my_release( const char *path, struct fuse_file_info *fi)
  if(!strcmp(path, "/example"))
    return -ENOENT;
  LOGGING("RELEASED %ld\n", fi->fh); // fh field set by my_open
  // Cleaning up some allocated buffers for fh here
  return 0;  
}
static struct fuse_operations fops = {
  // ... other callbacks
  .release  = my_release,
}
```

Is there some other function I should be using to implement a close callback?